# How to install an old version of gcc using yum on fedora 18?

Tags: linux, fedora, gcc

I want to install gcc 3.6 on fedora 18.

when I do yum install gcc

I get the gcc 4.7. but I want an old version.

Comment: May I ask why you want this?

Comment: to install qemu. 
as it has problems with new gcc. 

recommended to use gcc 3.6

Comment: ... Why not use the QEMU that comes with Fedora?

Comment: I'm doing some work with qemu. changine source codes so I need to reinstall from source using gcc 3.6

Comment: Perhaps you should invest some time into figuring out how they got it to build with 4.7.

Comment: I did but there're A LOT of errors. So, I prefer to stick with the recommendations

Comment: Did you mean 3.4.6, and not 3.6? Regardless, use a gcc hosting site like [Netgull](http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/) and download the tar for the version you want. If you can't do run level 5 and are stuck at the command line, get the full link on another device and use wget to pull the tar on your F18 machine. From there you should just need to extract the tar and run ./configure. I don't think old versions of GCC are available through yum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're prepared to settle for gcc version 3.4 instead, try:

```
yum install compat-gcc-34
```

if not, then you'll have to build your own from a source tarball on the gnu website:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/

The build process will take quite some time, but it's simple enough.