# Recommended way to provide another version of GCC?

Tags: fedora, gcc

I'm on Fedora 23 which installs GCC 5.3.1 by default.

For a cross compilation project with libraries which have been compiled with GCC 4.9 I'd like to install GCC 4.9 in parallel.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/619102/how-to-install-an-old-version-of-gcc-using-yum-on-fedora-18) (very old) post describes how to do this for GCC 3.8 and recommends to build any other version from scratch.

Now it's 3 years later - Is there a way to provide an older version of GCC in a separate directory (using the package manager) which can be used in parallel to the installed GCC 5.3?

Comment: GCC 4.9 is not packaged explicitly in [official repository](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/search?match=glob&type=package&terms=compat-gcc*). So you will probably have to build it on your own. You can use the `compat-gcc` packages as an example

Answer (score 8):

This is **NOT** an answer to my question since I only show how to build and use GCC 4.9 in a way which works on Fedora 23 (and on any other platform probably, too). It's only the compilation of steps I had to do to compile with another version of GCC than the shipped one.

The shown steps are taken from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC).

- lookup and download and exctract the appropriate archive from http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/mirrors.html:

  ```
  wget ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/languages/gcc/releases/gcc-4.9.3/gcc-4.9.3.tar.bz2
  mkdir src; cd src
  tar xf ../gcc-4.9.3.tar.bz2
  ```
- download prerequisites:

  ```
  cd gcc-4.9.3
  ./contrib/download_prerequisites
  ```
- configure the build (add `--disable-multilib` when you don't need a 32 bit build, set the install-`prefix`, add/remove languages):

  ```
  mkdir ../objdir; cd ../objdir
  ../gcc-4.9.3/configure \
      --prefix=`pwd`/../../gcc-4.9.3-x86_64 \
      --enable-languages=c,c++ \
      --disable-multilib
  ```
- actually build and install GCC:

  ```
  make -j4
  make install
  ```

You can now use this new compiler by just setting `CC` (maybe also `CXX`) before you run `make` or `cmake`:

```
export CC=</installation/path/to/gcc>/bin/gcc
make .
```

or

```
CC=</installation/path/to/gcc>/bin/gcc cmake <path>
```